# Howto do a input-box with proposal drop-down after some characters are entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am searching for a solution in Javascript/JQuery to have a simple input-field but after some characters are entered there will be a proposal drop-down box where the user can choose from one of the given Inputs, or if the user doesn't want to, keep going entering a new one.

I searched a lot, does anyone here know how to do that?

Comment: Is this at all helpful: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ It seems to provide the functionality you need

Comment: @OliverRadini: Thanks, that's exactly what I searched.

Answer (score -1):

Should try this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

for DEMO:

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/)

Comment: You may want to mention that this is from the JQuery UI docs which are already linked.